# Why can't an annotated variable be global?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, global-variables

Running

```py
def function():
    global global_values
    global_values: str = []
```

gives

```
SyntaxError: annotated name 'global_values' can't be global
```

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I got the same error when using `global` and `type annotation` INSIDE a function. Putting the `type annotation` in the global space solved it.

PS: Executing the lines of code that you proposed in python 3.8.8 does not generate any error in my setup.

Comment: @Mike I'm getting this SyntaxError, while having the type annotation in global space and the global statement within a function. Also within Python 3.10 I get the same error. The OP should have put the statement within a function (as it doesn't make sense to use a global keyword in the global space, i think)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been explained in [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations):

> It is illegal to attempt to annotate variables subject to `global` or
> `nonlocal` in the same function scope:

```
def f():
    global x: int  # SyntaxError

def g():
    x: int  # Also a SyntaxError
    global x
```

> The reason is that `global` and `nonlocal` don't own variables; therefore,
> the type annotations belong in the scope owning the variable.

The solution is to annotate the variable *outside* the function (i.e., in the global namespace), and remove type annotations inside the function's scope.

Comment: What does that mean? So how do you type annotate a global??

Comment: @uchuugaka It means that the only place you can annotate a global variable is in its own scope, IE in the global scope.

Comment: So we can just write `x: int` before calling the mehods. It's probably best to annotate the variable there anyway when we declare it.

Answer (score 8):

So, as is often the case with very *old language features*, this is confusing.
**`global`** in python is a statement that declares a ***name*** to be matching a key in the `globals()` dictionary-like container.
If the key is not *already* in the `globals()` dictionary-like container, it will be added. It will default to a value of None at that time.
If a variable is assigned in the global scope (and defined at that time), then the variable's ***name*** is added to the `globals()` dictionary-like container and the ***value*** is set to the value for the key matching the ***name*** in the `globals()` dictionary-like container.

So, the ***global*** keyword is a statement that adds a name to that `globals()` dictionary-like container.
Unfortunately, you cannot do assignments to the variable in the same line as using ***global*** to add that variable's name to `globals()` dictionary-like container.

Because of this sadness, adding a name to `globals()` dictionary-like container will IMPLICITLY make it an Optional type in Python's typing world.

I still think this is a bug mentally. It is not obvious. It is not clear. It is not really sensible. Yet, there it is.

The right thing to do would be to have the ability to immediately assign a value to a global at the same time it is made global and thus have a non-Optional global type, and also remove the non-obvious, confusing troublesome edge case this is. Typing is great and would be lovely to have more of it in Python. It helps scale, it helps remove logical errors and ambiguities that cause difficult bugs. It highlights when you have situations where you have not accounted for a variable possibly being a type wholly incompatible with the code written.

Comment: Is it an edge case? Thanks for your nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

The given explanation of the accepted answer actually makes zero sense whatsoever, moreover it seems `annotating global variables` been the consensus as `should be allowed` in this discussion: https://bugs.python.org/issue34939, however as of yet - Python 3.8 - it hasn't been implemented.

The problem must be in the implementation rather than a logical one.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that the accepted answer makes no sense - it does and it answers the OP use case. Nonetheless, the link to the bug you mention is in fact exactly what I was looking for, because I have code that ran in Python 3.9.7 but showed the exact bug with 3.7.8. But the circumstances leading up to that bug are different from the OPs question.

Comment: The accepted answer is a quote but not an explanation of the error.

Comment: @uchuugaka true, the accepted answer quotes an explanation, and my answer says the given explanation quoted there makes no logical sense.

I've also given a link to people working on this "bug" that a global variable can't be annotated.